# Error Checking CheckBoxes

Tags: vba, excel

I have 6 CheckBoxes right now under an Audience category and want to make it so that they have to select at least 1 of the 6 CheckBoxes or an error message saying "Please select an Audience" will appear.

Right now with the code below, the project will still be entered regardless of if they check one of the 6 boxes or not.

My current code looks like:

```
Function CheckInputs() As Boolean
    If Not CheckControl(Me.nameTextbox, "Please enter your name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.projectTextbox, "Please enter a Project Name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.initiativeCombobox, "Please select an Initiative") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.impactCombobox, "Please select Impact Type") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox2, "Please enter project length") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.rvpCheckbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.umCheckbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.uwCheckbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.baCheckbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.uaCheckbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.otherCheckbox, "Please select an Audience") Then Exit Function


    CheckInputs = True
End Function

Private Function CountSelectedListBoxItems(lb As MSForms.ListBox) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    With lb
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then CountSelectedListBoxItems = CountSelectedListBoxItems + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Function

Function CheckControl(ctrl As MSForms.Control, errMsg As String) As Boolean
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "TextBox"
            CheckControl = Trim(ctrl.Value) <> ""
        Case "ComboBox"
            CheckControl = ctrl.ListIndex <> -1
        Case "ListBox"
            CheckControl = CountSelectedListBoxItems(ctrl) > 0
        Case "CheckBox"
            CheckControl = ctrl.Value = False
'        Case Else
    End Select
    If errMsg = "" Then Exit Function
    If CheckControl Then Exit Function
    ctrl.SetFocus
    MsgBox errMsg
End Function
```

Would setting a CheckControl function for CheckBox as ctrl.Value = False be the appropriate route? Or did I not set my CheckInputs function correctly?

Comment: Are the `CheckBoxes` on a `UserForm` or on a Sheet? If they are on a sheet. Did you use ActiveX `CheckBoxes` or Form Controls?

Comment: They are on a UserForm @Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems to me that (if I understand correctly) your `CheckInputs` function is currently incorrect.

The following line of code:

```
If Not CheckControl(Me.rvpCheckbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.umCheckbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.uwCheckbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.baCheckbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.uaCheckbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.otherCheckbox, "Please select an Audience") Then Exit Function
```

needs to be change to the following:

```
If UserForm1.rvpCheckbox.Value = False And _
    UserForm1.umCheckbox.Value = False And _
    UserForm1.uwCheckbox.Value = False And _
    UserForm1.baCheckbox.Value = False And _
    UserForm1.uaCheckbox.Value = False And _
    UserForm1.otherCheckbox.Value = False Then
        UserForm1.otherCheckbox.Caption = "Please select an Audience"
        '...or maybe a message box instead?
        MsgBox "Please select an Audience"
        Exit Function
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I'll try adding in a better function to make this applicable.